# robocopy as administrator ntuser.dat (not from the running OS partition) access denied

Tags: windows

```
Robocopy.exe G:\ F:\ /copyall /e /DCOPY:DAT /v /sl
```

gives

```
2021/07/06 01:14:08 ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Copying File G:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\NTUSER.DAT
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Waiting 30 seconds...
```

The currently running windows 2012 is located on C:.

`handle.exe|findstr -i "G:"` is empty (i.e. no open handle)

Im running as Administrator in powershell.

What can I do in order to copy the whole partition (preferably with windows utils)

Comment: `NTUser.dat` is the user Registry hive, so it's mounted in the Registry under `HKU\<SID>` when Windows loads _(junction to `HKCU` when user is logged in)_, so in order for a file operation to access it, you need to boot to WinRE/WinPE, else the hive can become corrupted.

Comment: Are you *sure* this isn't in use by the operating system? "Documents and Settings" is very much non-standard already.

Comment: As I said, C: is the running OS. G: is a different windows.

Comment: mhm, junction is a hardlink right? Does it only work on the same filesystem or may G: link to C: - which would explain an access violation

Comment: Probably there is a symlink or junction on G and I I am not sure `/sl` actually works with robocopy. You might try `/XJ`, `/XJD` and/or `/XJF`. YOu might check *when* in the verbose output this happens to track down any link. It may be set silently in a group policy via domain etc.

Comment: Where is this junction you are referring to? No, junctions are not hard links.

Comment: The OP includes the flag `/sl` which is an instruction to not dive into links, and the OP has stated repeatedly that the quoted folder is not supposed to be in that path. Just a clue. But "Documents and Settings" is (by default in win10 I think) a junction to "users". NTFS links can be "hard links," "junction points," and or "symbolic links" but we have no way of knowing which it is, if it is, and why it is nor how it is. these folders are often redirected via domain policy to a server etc.

Comment: Ah, right, the XP backwards compatibility thing. That might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Volume Shadow Copy (VSS)](https://ubackup.com/windows-10/shadow-copy-windows-10-4348.html) or disk-imaging software using VSS to copy the F: drive, rather than Robocopy.

[Data Hamster explains how to use Robocopy with VSS](https://datahamster.com/2018/04/06/using-shadow-copy-with-robocopy/) to copy otherwise inaccessible files.

Another way to do this is using any [disk imaging software](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/free-windows-10-disk-imaging-software.html) that allows you to browse the files in the saved image. Make a disk image (an essential backup to have, anyway, should an issue occur), browse the image to find the file(s), and copy from that image.

Since the Registry is continually being written to during a Windows session, its contents may change at any time, perhaps while it is being copied. For that reason, Windows prevents certain  system files from being be accessed *directly*. Apparently, it protects those files on F: as part of the Registry, though not in active use.

Comment: its not the current system partition. There should be no file handle...

Comment: @user1457678, yes, you are correct and the answer has been rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here’s what’s happening.

For backwards compatibility with Windows XP, there’s still a *junction* at `C:\Documents and Settings` that points at `C:\Users`. A junction is not a symlink.

The path `C:\Users` is absolute, so even if it’s `G:\Documents and Settings`, it *still* points at `C:\Users`.

On your Robocopy command line, you specified `/SL` but not `/SJ`, so Robocopy tried to copy the files at `C:\Users` when it encountered `G:\Documents and Settings`.

So just add `/SJ` and you should be good.